# Different PersistenceConfig.java for development and production

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Below is the PersistenceConfig.java file which I use for development. However in production, that would look quite different since I'm using postgresql there. What is a good way to deal with that? So I'm not forced into a if-else hell.

```
import ...;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
//      factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring Profiles to differentatie between environments. I would configure everything for production and just override for dev. Also move some properties to a properties file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // Production configuration
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
//      factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(env.getProperty("hibernate.show-sql", Boolean.class, false));
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(env.getProperty("hibernate.generate-schema", Boolean.class, false));
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" );
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("dev")
    public static class DevPersistenceConfig {
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();      
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that should work. The defaults are configured for production and when the profile `dev` is active (can be set using the `spring.profiles.active` property as environment variable) then the datasource will be overridden by the one in the `DevPersistenceConfig` class.

The dialect can be set using an entry in the `application.properties` file (or whatever you like to name it).

Comment: I have a profile called openshift in my pom file. Can I simply create a class called OpenshiftPersistenceConfig and have that loaded when the profile in question is active? I have a hard time understanding this since PersistenceConfig is just some arbitary name I have given that class.

Comment: Maven profiles and spring profiles have nothing to do with each other... Have you looked at the code and noticed the `@Profile` annotation?

Comment: No I missed that annotation! Thanks!