# Profile methods not loading

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use spring profiles to have a persistence configuration for development and one for production called openshift. I can see that my openshift profile is loaded by none of my methods are called... judging by the lack of log messages. Anyone got a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

```
import ...;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-${envTarget:default}.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"dk.fitfit.campusfood.model", "dk.fitfit.campusfood.repository"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataInitializer dataInitializer;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private final String packagesToScan = "dk.fitfit.campusfood.*";


    public PersistenceConfig() {
        logger.info("PersistenceConfig loaded!");
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("jdbc.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    // Activate this profile on openshift by running: rhc set-env JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Dspring.profiles.active=openshift -a campusfood
    @Configuration
    @Profile("openshift")
    public static class OpenShiftPersistenceConfig {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpenShiftPersistenceConfig.class);

        private String driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        private String database = "campusfood";
        private String url = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL") + "/" + database;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstructor()
        {
            logger.info("OpenShiftPersistenceConfig loaded!");
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            logger.info("jpaVendorAdapter()");
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
            vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
            return vendorAdapter;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource()
        {
            logger.info("dataSource()");
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
            dataSource.setUrl(url);
            return dataSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

persistence-openshift.properties

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################
jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

persistence-default.properties

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################
jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: Why duplicate the whole configuration? Only a few things are different (as I stated in [the initial thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529300/different-persistenceconfig-java-for-development-and-production/26529468#26529468) you created). Also `@Autowired` on `static` fields won't work and I believe only a single method can be annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: The methods duplicated all differs slightly from the parent class. Can I do it differently? I assumed this was a somewhat new issue and thus made a new thread. How can I access the autowired class in the child class if not static? The specs does indeed state that ony one method can be annotated with @PostConstruct... yet both ran.

Comment: They aren't different only the properties differ, those properties you can put in a properties file (as I explained in the other thread). The only thing you need is the other datasource and apparently you want a initializer executed in the case of the openshift profile. Then just inject the bean in the other config.

Comment: I tried to trim it down and updated my post but ended up with the exception which I also posted. Any clue?

Comment: As stated you only need the datasource. The `jpaVendorAdapter` can be configured with properties. I also suspect that your `DataInitializer` has a dependency on the `EntityManagerFactory`. I suggest not to autowire it and just add a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` to it. You should add the `dataSource` as am ethod argument, the same goes for the `entityManagerFactory` for the transaction manager. This is all in the initial post you made... Please take a look at that. Finally your additional properties don't make sense as you are configuring those already on `HibernteJpaVendorAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration should look something like this.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-${envTarget:default}.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"dk.fitfit.campusfood.model", "dk.fitfit.campusfood.repository"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataInitializer dataInitializer;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private final String packagesToScan = "dk.fitfit.campusfood";


    public PersistenceConfig() {
        logger.info("PersistenceConfig loaded!");
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform( env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.hibernate.dialect"));
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Profile("!openshift")
    @Configuration 
    public static class DefaultPersistenceConfig { 
        @Bean 
        public DataSource dataSource() { 
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder() 
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) 
            .build(); 
        }
    }

    // Activate this profile on openshift by running: rhc set-env JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Dspring.profiles.active=openshift -a campusfood
    @Configuration
    @Profile("openshift")
    public static class OpenShiftPersistenceConfig {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpenShiftPersistenceConfig.class);

        private String driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        private String database = "campusfood";
        private String url = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL") + "/" + database;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstructor()t
        {
            logger.info("OpenShiftPersistenceConfig loaded!");
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource()
        {
            logger.info("dataSource()");
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
            dataSource.setUrl(url);
            return dataSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are no more `additionalProperties` as those were already set using the vendor adapter. The dialect is set based on the property and using the `databasePlatform` property on the vendor adapter.

The dependencies needed for the `EntityManagerFactory` are now part of the method signature, Spring will inject those when needed.

Your packagesToScan was also wrong it isn't a pattern but a package name.

If your `DataInitializer` has a dependency on the `EntityManagerFactory` you will run into trouble as you now have a circular dependency. Don't autowire it, if you want something done add a `@PostContruct` annotated method to the `DataInitializer`.

Comment: I still can't get it to load! https://github.com/tonsV2/CampusFood/blob/master/src/main/java/dk/fitfit/campusfood/config/PersistenceConfig.java - Any clue?

Comment: Your on unix so a `.` probably won't work try `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` instead of `spring.profiles.active`.

Comment: According to logger.info("env.getActiveProfiles(): {}", env.getActiveProfiles()) the profile is active.

Comment: Ok. But what happens, you get a stacktrace or is it still using the other `DataSource`?

Comment: Just using the wrong dataSource. When I'm testing locally I expect an exception to be thrown... but it's simply using the wrong dataSource. And same goes when testing remotely.

Comment: Looking at your code at least all your package/component-scans are flawed. It isn't a pattern but a base package, remove the ending `.*`in those.

Comment: So it still is using H2 instead of PostgreSQL? You would expect an exception because you don't have PostgreSQL on your machine? Which profiles are active? Do you see in your logs that the `OpenShiftPersistenceConfig` is even loaded or not?

Comment: You mean @ComponentScan from ApplicationConfig.java? No, I would expect an exception because System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL") will be null locally. And yes, my logs shows: INFO : dk.fitfit.campusfood.config.PersistenceConfig$OpenShiftPersistenceConfig - OpenShiftPersistenceConfig loaded!

Comment: Tip instead of `System.getenv` simply use the `Environment` that will also look in the system properties. Doe you also see the datasource info message? Try adding `@Primary` to the `dataSource()` method in the `OpenShiftPersistenceConfig` config class or move the normal datasource to another configuration class like `DefaultPersistenceConfig` so that just one of them is loaded.

Comment: Another, unrelated thing, is that you seem to be mixing spring versions (4.0.6 and 3.2.10) probably due to some transitive dependencies. That will probably lead to some other errors later.

Comment: How should I use Environment... it's an interface? (sorry for being a n00b here) I see PersistenceConfig.dataSource() but not OpenShiftPersistenceConfig.dataSource()... as I'd love to see! :). Thanks ill fix the version issue.

Comment: I found no mention of 3.2.10. Where do you see that?

Comment: Just like you do the other properties `env.getProperty("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL")`.

Comment: If I look at the dependencies I see 3.2.10 version of spring-jdbc, spring-orm and spring-tx. Probably due to the fact that Sprnig Data JPA depends on those and you haven't overridden them. Tip use the [Spring BOM](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-rc2-available) to fix versions. Or even better the [Spring IO Platform bom](https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/07/spring-io-platform-1-0-2-released) to have even more versions, that are garantueed to work together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63584/discussion-between-user672009-and-m-deinum).